# Is there a way to control which static resources gets cached using express

Tags: html, node.js, express

Using express I can set the max age for caching as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(path)), { maxAge: 1234567 });
```

There I have a html file which loads several scripts and style sheets. Is there any way to control the max-age for individual files? e.g. I would like to set my the age of JS libraries to 6 months and not cache files which change frequently.

Comment: Yes.  Write your own middleware.  It can wrap `express.static`.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I now realise that express.static has an optional setHeaders callback which is meant exactly for this purpose. I will try that first!

Comment: Cool, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to maxAge, from Express version 4 [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static?_ga=1.197973743.1554408370.1427746112) has an optional callback *setHeaders*. e.g.

```
var express = require('express');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var app = express();

app.use(serveStatic('/path/to/files/')), { 
    maxAge: 0 ,
    setHeaders : function (res, path) {
        if (path === '/path/to/files/vendor-bundle.min.js') {
            res.setHeader('Cache-Control', public, max-age=345600');
            res.setHeader('Expires', new Date(Date.now() + 345600000).toUTCString());
        }
    }
});
```

For **older versions of express** that do not support the *setHeaders* it is possible to write custom middleware (as commented above).

Comment: To future readers... setting both max-age and Expires is redundant. You only need one.